# Selecting several sums in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So I've come across a sum that I would like to get that I'm not sure how to. Here's my table:

```
#########################################
# Id # SiteID # TimeStamp  # Elecricity #
# 0  # 100    # 10/08/2012 # 50         #
# 1  # 98     # 10/08/2012 # 32         #
# 2  # 100    # 10/09/2012 # 96         #
# 3  # 94     # 10/09/2012 # 25         #
# 4  # 100    # 10/10/2012 # 100        #
# 5  # 100    # 10/11/2012 # 55         #
#########################################
```

What I'm trying to achieve is this: I want the SUM of electricity for each day for the sites 100 and 98. So for example, on the date 10/08/2012 the sum would be 50+32. for all the other days the sum would only be the electricity number of siteID 100.

If this makes sense and is possible, please let me know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select TimeStamp,sum(electricity) from
the_table
where SiteId in(98,100)
group by TimeStamp
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT TimeStamp, SUM(Electricity) FROM Table GROUP BY DATE(TimeStamp)
```

If you want to limit it to just those two sites, you will need

```
SELECT TimeStamp, SUM(Electricity) FROM Table WHERE SiteID IN (98,100) GROUP BY DATE(TimeStamp)
```